# What would be the consequences of semi-asynchronous exception handling in GHC?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception

I'm worried that approach to asynchronous exceptions in `GHC` might be a net-loss for many applications.

While [the paper](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/async.pdf) explains the design to a great detail, it's too complex for average programmers to tell whether this approach provides any benefits at all in their daily work.

Section 2 lists four reasons for current approach (speculative computation, timeouts, user interrupt and resource exhaustion). In my opinion, three are about ability to cancel computations and one is about ability to recover from resource exhaustion which I find questionable (is there any publicly available code that demonstrates this?).

In particular, as mentioned in the paper, `Java` deprecated `Thread.stop()` because aborted computation would result in undefined state. Aren't `IO` actions in `GHC` subject to the same? Add laziness and the API becomes much more complex in comparison for no clear benefit to most applications.

To summarize, if `GHC` used the same approach as `Java` (safe-points, interrupt polling) what would be the consequences to the ecosystem?

Comment: if you don't get any answers here, you should ask [the Haskell-Cafe mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-cafe) or [/r/haskell](http://reddit.com/r/haskell).